# Thermal management in FPGA

Tags: vhdl, temperature

I’m doing a thermal management application using Virtex®-6 FPGA ML605 Evaluation Kit. The whole idea is to send voltage input to ADC of system monitor in the FPGA present in ML506 and use on board sensors to sense the ADC output in terms of temperature. Since I’m new to this, I need help to accomplish this. Any suggestions are welcome. 
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to instantiate the SYSMON component in your in your design, setting all the generics as you like (averaging, internal ref, etc.). Then you have to convert the ADC codes to real values by implementing a transfer function, either by using RAM/LUTs as a look-up table, or by using multipliers. The transfer function is given in the user guide. You also have to check the schematics for you development board to find out how you can connect to the external analog input pins.

A good place to start if you haven't already done so is to download the user guide 'ug370'. Fetch the example design, and have a look. Xilinx supplies a behavioral model for the SYSMON, it works well and is very useful. It's pretty straight forward.

[UG370](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug370.pdf)

[Example design](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug192.zip)